# Error in mocking service invocation

Tags: grails, service, spock, integration-testing

The error was on integration test of a service. Yes, we're currently doing integration test on our service as a workaround since we cannot test the services via unit test due to userType mapping.

Regarding userType: Our Domain uses interface as properties. In addition findBy*interface* won't work on grails.

see below:

```
class Domain {
    SomeProperty someProperty
    String otherProperty
}

public interface SomeProperty {
    //methods
}

enum Enum implements SomeProperty {
    NAME,
    OTHERNAME

    //implementation of methods
}
```

class Domain can handle different kinds of enum implementing the SomeProperty inteface. 
Database won't know what particular value should it saved so we go with the userType. below is the Domain with the mapping

```
class Domain {
    SomeProperty someProperty
    String otherProperty
}

static mapping = {
    id generator: 'sequence', column: 'id', params: [sequence: 'domain_sequence']
    someProperty type : userType, {
        column name: "someProperty", sqlType: "varchar", length: 255
    }
}
```

Updated:

Code being tested:

```
class ServiceBeingTested {

AnotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested //or def anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested

    public void methodBeingTested(param1, param2, param3) {

        Object object = privateMethod(..., ...) //private method contains no other service calls. just pure logic
        anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested.voidMethod1(....)
        anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested.voidMethod2(....)

    }
}
```

My integration test:

```
class ServiceBeingTestedIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

ServiceBeingTested serviceBeingTested = new ServiceBeingTested()
AnotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested   

    void setUp () {
        anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested = Mock()
        serviceBeingTested.anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested = anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested
    }

    void cleanup () {
        //code here
    }

    void "methodBeingTested should invoke the 2 service method call"() {
        given:
        //initialize data here
        //code

        when:
        serviceBeingTested.methodBeingTested(param1, param2, param3)

        then:
        1 * anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested.voidMethod1(....)
        1 * anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested.voidMethod2(....)
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
|  Too few invocations for:
1 * anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested.voidMethod2(....)   (0 invocations)
Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
1 * anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested.this$3$voidMethod2(....)
```

The other service call with same anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested -i.e anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested.voidMethod1 was correctly invoked. I tried changing the parameters in test for voidMethod2 to wildcards but will still result to this error.

Thanks

Comment: just to add. Noticed that we were mocking other service calls than to let it execute what the actual void methods do, this is because unit tests can't handle userType mappings of our domain model and that we wanted to conduct unit test for it. Thus, the same behaviour of testing style of unit tests but was just via integration test spec

Comment: mind if someone can comment why the downvote? i'll update the question if necessary. tnx

Comment: what is service variable ? and what is userType relationship that you are talking about. Please edit / update your post with these details.

Comment: Just to clarify on the issue. Method *voidMethod2* was a private method the whole time.

    anotherServiceInsideServiceBeingTested.this$3$voidMethod2(....)

Answer (score 0):

In integration test cases, you don't need to mock any of the services as these are available by default as the full application is loaded. 
Though, in unit test, you may use @TestFor annotation and specify the service which you want to test, this will inject a service variable which would be available through you specification / test class.

```
@TestFor(Service)
class ServiceBeingTestedIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

ServiceBeingTested serviceBeingTested = new ServiceBeingTested()   

    void setUp () {
        serviceBeingTested.service = service
    }

    void cleanup () {
        //code here
    }

    void "methodBeingTested should invoke the 2 service method call"() {
        given:
        //initialize data here
        //code

        when:
        serviceBeingTested.methodBeingTested(param1, param2, param3)

        then:
        1 * service.voidMethod1(....)
        1 * service.voidMethod2(....)
    }
}
```

Also, in case above you could also try to stub your methods in setup after mocking these to avoid any other service called by your service which will throw NullPointerException and eventually your test would fail in case of unit tests.

example of stubbing could be:

```
1*service.voidMethod1 >> {
      //some code setting up any data for you.
}


1*service.voidMethod2 >> {
      //some code setting up any data for you.
}
```

If you use stubbing like above you can simply write down unit test cases as well.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure if I understood your answer above correctly. But on our case, we can't go with the Unit test since userTypes won't work on that environment - thus an integration test as a workaround but somewhat behave like of a unit test(mocking of other service calls). As for the test, I want to ensure that voidMethod1 and voidMethod2 are called regardless of what these methods will do. In addition, service calls interaction test i think wont return null pointers. not sure though. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the time. after an hour of rechecking. voidMethod2 is a private method of the service i wanted to check the calls. i should known the stacktrace "this" :) thanks. shame on me :))